# Python Kivy выдаёт ошибку UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, kivy

Я зaпускаю код на Kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class DuckyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DuckyApp().run()
```

И получаю такую ошибку

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Natalia_Amir\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-10-18_74.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "D:\Python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\Python\app\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.button import Button
   File "D:\Python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\button.py", line 49, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.label import Label
   File "D:\Python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 286, in <module>
     from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel, DEFAULT_FONT
   File "D:\Python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\__init__.py", line 1006, in <module>
     Text = Label = core_select_lib('text', label_libs)
   File "D:\Python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 103, in core_select_lib
     'identify potential causes\n{1}'.format(category.capitalize(), err))
   File "C:\Users\Natalia_Amir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1379, in critical
     self._log(CRITICAL, msg, args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Natalia_Amir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1468, in _log
     self.handle(record)
   File "C:\Users\Natalia_Amir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1478, in handle
     self.callHandlers(record)
   File "C:\Users\Natalia_Amir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1540, in callHandlers
     hdlr.handle(record)
   File "C:\Users\Natalia_Amir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 854, in handle
     self.emit(record)
   File "D:\Python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py", line 247, in emit
     self._write_message(message)
   File "D:\Python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py", line 218, in _write_message
     stream.write(fs % msg)
   File "C:\Users\Natalia_Amir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 250-251: character maps to <undefined>
```

Пожалуйста подскажите как это исправить?

*Я использовал* **PyCharm**

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка из-за того, что в логгере не была задана кодировка и использовалась системная, т.е. `cp1252`.

Сейчас, самая свежая устанавливаемая версия 1.11.1, это в логгере выглядит так:

```
FileHandler.fd = open(filename, 'w')
```

А [с исправлением](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/4b450ccf5b7cf33ce7fe283a4b9c68fdc6a2c43f#diff-a6dd835b35a21d1ba496b60a3fa7c04aa7e2475f2c9e8f23e27ff93a3e6597a3) (в master, версия 2.0.0 уже есть исправление) так:

```
FileHandler.fd = open(filename, 'w', encoding=FileHandler.encoding)
```

, где `FileHandler.encoding = 'utf-8'`

---

Т.е. **первый вариант** -- руками пропатчить файл `logger.py` поменяв `FileHandler.fd = open(filename, 'w')`:

```
FileHandler.fd = open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

**Второй вариант** поставить версию из `master` ветки, где это уже исправлено, попробуйте:

```
pip install kivy==2.0.0rc4
```

После установки версия другая и в `logger.py` ошибка исправлена:

```
import kivy
print(kivy.__version__)
# 2.0.0rc4
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно пойти на официальный сайт kivy (kivy.org). Зайти в раздел download. А за тем установить все обновления и дополнительные библиотеки по инструкции.

Comment: Нa официальный сайт пойти нельзя — он забанен.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, у кого забанен?

Comment: @Qwertiy Как выяснилось уже разбанен ;)